# Why am I just a number?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

URL's are supposed to be user-friendly, so why is it we can access:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/3856039/bonner

But not:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/bonner

Facebook has provided the ability to add custom aliases, yet Stack Overflow doesn't.

The lack of a user-friendly URL makes me feel like just a number, as after-all I'm being identified as `3856039` and not `bonner`.

Comment: Luckily we are not Facebook ...

Answer (score 25):

You are not the only `Bonner` on Stack Overflow.

We don't limit display names to be unique - the number is there so we know which exact user you are trying to fetch on that page.

Comment: Would it not be confusing if two users with the same name were involved in the same discussion, one asks a question and the other provides an answer, both with the same name?

Comment: @Bonner: Yes, we have chat rooms where a single "@Matt" pings at least half a dozen people simultaneously.

Comment: So is this not considered an issue, are people happy with how it currently works?

Comment: @Bonner I guess they were happier to have names like "Bonner2018" or "Tom12345" because the original name was already taken by an user who posted a single question several years ago. SO has way too many users to restrict usernames to be unique. This would require a lot of gibberish added to the name, because the "clean version" was already taken.

Comment: Just out of curiousity - will the http://stackoverflow.com/users/number/name be still valid if the user changes their name?

Comment: I can type anything after the id/ and I get the same account: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3856039/bonner123

Comment: @Bonner `are people happy with how it currently works?` Yes, a lot of us consider this system to be vastly superior to one with unique user names that force people into all sorts of weird variations because their real name was already taken.

Comment: @Bonner웃 - sure. You can do that. And the page will redirect you to the current display name you set.

Comment: I am not a number, I am a free...wait, I'm number 6471538.

Comment: @Oded I was answering the question Sebastian asked.

Comment: Fair enough, @Bonner웃 :)

Answer (score 12):

> Why am I just a number?

Because then there could be only one `bonner`, and you would likely be something like `bonner29` which is arguably even *more* degrading than just a number.

Comment: Wait, are you the real Pekka? You might be [that imposter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1870917/pekka)

Comment: @Machavity that user can't be for real; he states he still has things to learn. I, on the other hand, am already perfect.